# Converting multiple fields with abbreviations to one field with full names in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-expression

I have a field with singular abbreviations (`"BB"`, `"BC"`, `and "BG"`) that corresponds to a table with full names (catfish, rainbow trout). It ranges from 1-10 abbreviations delimited by commas.

This is an example of the data.

[image]

What statement or process could I use to take these abbreviations and get them into one field with the full names expressed minus all the extra commas?

In the picture below, the column `"APPENDED"` has the abbreviations and the `"Species"` is what I want to fill in with the first one manually completed.

[image]

Comment: Not clear. Please add example of resust you need.

Comment: Like a comma separated text? `Something, SomethingElse, blabla`

Comment: BTW QGIS expression for string concatenation of attributes a, b and c: concat("a","b","c") or "a" || "b" || "c"

Comment: OP, I hope you manage to edit the question so that it can be opened again, and that you can mark any answer as the solution if they have answered your query - otherwise the question and answer get buried and won't be as easily referenced by people with the same issue.

Comment: Your updated edit should also include what reference you are using to match up each abbreviation to the full name (e.g. BK = brook trout, RB = rainbow trout). Is there a lookup table (e.g. excel file or CSV) in your project? That would be the easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using arrays to concatenate your data, especially as you will have some blank/null results which will make typical concatenate (`||`) not work well and you would need to wrap each field around with a `coalesce()` which is time-consuming.

You mention full names without any additional info - I will assume you have a separate table in your QGIS project that acts as a lookup table, something like below as an example.

| abbr | fullname |
| --- | --- |
| BB | Cutfish |
| BC | Rainbow Trout |
| BG | Mahi-mahi |

Let's call this lookup layer `LookupTable` and the layer in your screenshot above as `FishObs`.

*Assume the names of all the fields you want to concatenate start with FISH.*

1. Select the `FishObs` layer in your list of layers and open Field Calculator.
2. Select an appropriate text field you want to enter the concatenated value into (Update existing field), or create a new field of text type and sufficient length.
3. Use this expression:

```
array_to_string(
    array_filter(
        array_foreach(
         array_filter(map_akeys(attributes()),
                      @element ilike 'FISH%'),
        attribute(get_feature('LookupTable','abbr',eval(@element)),
       'fullname')),
    @element is not null),
', ')
```

Example result:

[image]

The full names are in the order of the fields as they appear, but you can further order the array using `array_sort()` in between `array_to_string()` and `array_filter()` above.

---

Step by step explanation:

1. **Generate list of field names** as an array using `map_akeys(attributes())`. I believe by default this array is alphabetically sorted.
2. **Filter field name array** to only those starting with FISH (`array_filter()`, condition `@element ilike 'FISH%'`)
3. **Evaluate each field name** in the array from Step 2, using `array_foreach()` and `eval(@element)`. `eval()` takes the field name and treats it like a field *reference*, turning e.g., 'FISH1' from a text string in the array of field names, to "FISH1" a field reference that yields a value for each feature. — This will result in an array like `['BC','BN','RB','','','','']`, with `''` appearing where evaluating a field returns an empty value (e.g. see `FISH4` to `FISH7` in features 12-14 in screenshot).
4. **Lookup the full name** while iterating over each evaluated value in the array from step 3, using `LookupTable` and the functions `get_feature()`. First this matches `eval(@element)` (e.g. `'BC'`) to the record in `LookupTable` with a matching `attr` value, and then `attribute()`, returns the corresponding `fullname` value for that record (i.e., `BC` returning `Rainbow Trout`). Now your array will look like `['Rainbow Trout','Swordfish','Mackerel',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL]` because looking up an empty value returns `NULL`.
5. **Exclude `NULL` values** from the arrays in step 4 using `array_filter()` and `@element IS NOT NULL`. This means you now get an array like `['Rainbow Trout','Swordfish','Mackerel']` for features 12-14, `['Cutfish','Yellowfin Tuna']` for feature 2, etc. This solves the issue of blank/NULL values that plague most concatenate solutions.
6. **Concatenate the array into a string** using `array_to_string()` and your preferred concatenator (here, `', '`). Simply turns the array (shown with square brackets `['Cutfish', 'Yellowfin Tuna']`) to a string (`'Cutfish, Yellowfin Tuna'`). This is required so that it can actually be depicted in your dataset.

---

Customisations:

- **Re-order the concatenated fields** - at step 2, use `array_sort()` at this stage to order the fields, or `array_prioritize()` if you wish to manually specify an order that is not alphabetical.
- **Capitalisation, extra text etc** - at step 4, use `lower()`, `||'text'` etc around the last parameter of `array_foreach()`.
- **Add text in front of the concatenated array** - simply add `'Your text here '||` to the front of the whole expression. `||' Your text here'` at the back of the whole expression for text at the back.
- **Return some other value where there are no resulting values at all**, e.g. feature 1 in screenshot where result shows as `NULL` - use `coalesce()` around entire expression. E.g. `coalesce(expression, 'No records found')` so that 'No records found' is returned in case of `NULL`.
- **Change concatenator** e.g. from comma to semicolon, no space, - change accordingly in step 6

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the Field Calculator and tick the option "Create a new field", as in the following picture:

[image]

- One method could be simply using `concat("FISH2", "FISH3")`.
- A second method, and my preferred one, would be simply using `||`. For example, using the expression `"FISH2" || "FISH3"`. In case you want to add a blank space between abbreviations, you should add it as follows: `"FISH2" || ' ' || "FISH3"`